# Is Azure SQL (PaaS) certified for use on Sharepoint hosted in Microsoft Azure? Performant?

Tags: sql-server, azure, sharepoint, azure-sql-database

Looking to help a customer migrate their Sharepoint to Azure along with a lot of their other virtual workloads.  I'd rather not use the Office 365 Sharepoint product.  Rather host Sharepoint on IaaS and either the supporting SQL Server on a BYOL/IaaS VM or use the managed Azure SQL (if possible).  I can't seem to locate that certification information and would also be interested in anyone's experience.

Answer (score 2):

Hosting SharePoint databases on SQL Azure is not officially supported but [this](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sambetts/2015/04/10/hosting-sharepoint-content-databases-in-sql-azure/) Microsoft blog post shows it is possible. It is not supported because SQL Azure cannot guarantee 1 ms latency required by SharePoint as explained on the article. If you don’t like SharePoint online then you should install all SharePoint servers on Azure VMs.

Hope this helps.

Regards,

Alberto Morillo

Answer (score 1):

This is great question (I have no idea why did he get a negative points), and I would like to give an updated answer (for today) even so it is an old thread from a year ago, since we have new features today. It is important to mention that the answer today is probably YES (you can use it for most cases), although it is still not officially documented/supported.

First, let me repeat what I said that officially it is still not supported, but probably only because no one documented it yet and you should test it.

In the blog that Alberto mentioned (it is from **2015**) Sam Betts says that you should make sure the region of the Azure SQL Database is the same as your SharePoint servers region in order to avoid latency. In 2015 that was the only recommendation, since you had no control over the vNet of your Azure SQL Database.

On February 2018 [Microsoft announced](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/vnet-service-endpoints-for-azure-sql-database-now-generally-available/) the general availability of Virtual Network (VNet) Service Endpoints for Azure SQL Database in all Azure regions. In addition we have a new deployment option for Azure SQL Databases As A Service today named "[Managed Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-managed-instance)", which also allows us to control the vNet and to create for example Virtual Machines (and other elements) which use the same vNet.

If you want to use Azure SQL (PaaS) for SharePoint hosted in Microsoft Azure, you should make sure that you are working under the same region and under the same vNet. Without fully familiar with your system I cannot give direct absolute answer like **YES** or **NO**, and You should test the system but probably for most cases **it should fit**.